# How To Call jQuery Function From Another JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `main.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getScript('another.js', function() {
    another();
  });
});
```

...and the following `another.js`

```
$(function another() {
  $('section#my-section').after('<a href="#">my link</a>');
});
```

The directory structure is as follows:

```
+ my.html
+ js
  +--- main.js
  +--- another.js
```

`another()` is never called.  Why?  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the order your files are being called in your HTML file. Make sure that the actual function is loaded before the other file that calls it.

Comment: @NickDugger not in this case... You clearly did not read the code.

Comment: Do I have to include them both?  Won't $.getScript() fetch the another.js file without having to explicitly link to it in the HTML?

Comment: @NickDugger — `main.js` imports `another.js` programmatically, so it doesn't.

Comment: My bad, I don't use jQuery. I didn't recognize the getScript function.

Comment: OK. The solution is a combination of Quentin's and mohammedrias' suggestions and this: $.getScript('js/another.js',...  Apparently the path is in relation to html file and not main.js

Answer (score 4):

You've defined `another` using a function expression and have passed it to `$()`.

You need to make it a global.

Since you are calling it after you include it anyway, you presumably don't need to pass it to `$()`, so just get rid of that wrapper around it and it will be a function declaration (and a global).

Comment: ^^ This, why does everyone think that every function call has to be wrapped in a jquery wrapper, or be an annon function??????

Comment: LoL, had heard that before but first time I actually read the wiki article. Sad but most likely true.

Comment: This doesn't work.  The debugger never gets to the line where another() is called.

Comment: @Peter — How are you testing? It you are stepping through, it won't, since it isn't run linearly. You'd need a breakpoint inside the callback function. Failing that, make sure that the right script is loading. Check the Net tab in the developer tools to make sure the URL is correct and the response is what you expect. Check the JS console for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to consider:

At first you can't call another() inside main.js because it's wrapped inside $() and its not available in global scope. So you need to remove that another();

So your code in `another.js` will be like

```
function another() {
  $('section#my-section').after('<a href="#">my link</a>');
}
```

Then If you are testing this in your local using chrome browser it may not work.

Because **`chrome`** doesn't support local ajax call and it will give `XMLHttpRequest cannot load`

Anyways in `firefox` and other browsers it will work fine.

Just you need to load the `main.js` after `jquery`

I have tested your code in my local using firefox and it worked fine.

Comment: `$(function another() {...});` cannot work as expected when trying to call `another()` method again. That's said, following OP's code, OP doesn't need to recall this method on $.getScript() success callback, doesn't make sense

Comment: Strange, but it just worked.. I also tested it thrice before making this answer :P

Comment: So you are testing in some way wrongly, try to call `another()` method, it should be undefined on global scope. e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/8QNDU/ Here, it should be alerted twice, not only once

Comment: yes, we can't call another() from outside as its wrapped by jquery. But when the file another.js is getting loaded the code inside the function executed

Comment: I tried to execute this in browser, $(function another() {
  alert("rias");
}); and it given me a alert

Comment: Because this is just like $(handler) so calling function on ready handler

Comment: so it means he just need to remove another() from main.js and the code will work fine???

Comment: I don't know how you are testing it but it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jz6ka/2/

Comment: I am testing it with actual files in my wamp server. BTW the   $.getScript('/echo/html', another); returns you no content and function another() {} is now in global scope so its getting invoked as a callback method. The actual issue arises when the function is present in the another.js which you can't mimic in jsfiddle

Comment: Ya, my bad, it must be: `$.getScript('another.js', function(){another()});`